# How to read excel file using pure C?

Tags: c, windows, linux, excel

As the title said, I have a task that I need to read data from excel files. I'm wondering how to implement it in pure C, not C++ or C#. Btw, I need to write and test the program in Linux but others may use the code in Windows, which means my code has to be OS independent. Thank you.

Comment: Is using the CSV format an option? Otherwise take a look here http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf and perhaps look/borrow the openoffice source code..

Comment: Another reference for the file format: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/%5BMS-XLS%5D.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Handcoding excel support in C is complex. You have to depend on third libraries. But If you just wanted to follow CSV format, you can write your own CSV parser.