# PHP Excel 504 nginx timeout at 400 records. Not able to export the excel file

Tags: php, excel, nginx, timeout

I am trying to export an excel file using PHP excel library. I can export about 400 records. However when I go for more about 600 records, I see nginx timeout error. I have been trying to resolve this issue. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

So far I have played with php options like.. set_time_limit(0); and ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

But still not able to resolve it.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Thanks for the replies. I contacted my server company and they said they had added fastcgi_read_timeout 360; to nginx setting. and it works now.

However, the download initiates very slowly. I guess its because of the PHP Excel Library. Can anyone suggest how I can get it to respond faster?

Comment: Have you looked at how efficiently you're retrieving your records, writing them to Excel, etc? i.e. at your code!

Comment: @MarkBaker download initiates very slowly. I guess its because of the PHP Excel Library. Can anyone suggest how I can get it to respond faster?

Comment: Start by telling us which PHP Excel library, and then show us how you're using it... otherwise my crystal ball isn't helping

Comment: @MarkBaker https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel This is the open source library I have been using. I see that you have added a few contributions to the project as well. Now I feel, you are the right one whom I can seek help.
I am passing a PHP array with contents as below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx error, so change nginx config

[proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_read_timeout)

Comment: download initiates very slowly. I guess its because of the PHP Excel Library. Can anyone suggest how I can get it to respond faster?

Comment: @PrashantBalan php is interpreted language, so it is slow by design. So as I understand you task, you can divide task to: upload file to server and parse file. After succesfull file upload show page with message `File parsing. Be patient etc`. On this page set ajax script which will be ask server 'do you finish' and display info to user. When file uploaded to server run background script which parse file. This is main idea

Comment: Thanks! Will try your idea. However I just wanted to know if I am going to scan through 5000 records there.. it will get worse and eventually time out again. Is there a way to optimize the time and memory usage. Because reading from the blogs, I found that memory can also become an issue.

Comment: @PrashantBalan Try to use parser writed on C/C++ or Java. All depends on you expirience and time which you can spend for speed optimisation. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826472/how-to-read-excel-file-using-pure-c

Comment: I need a web-based solution and something to go along PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few quick observations from looking at your code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($row,1);
```

is an expensive operation (and grows more expensive as the volume of data in your worksheet grows) that you're repeating for every iteration of your foreach() loop. Count how many rows you need, then insert that many new rows *before* looping.

For every cell you're writing, you're using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->...
```

this entails a call to the workbook's getActiveSheet() method for every cell.
Execute this once before the loop, storing the returned worksheet in a variable (e.g. $ws), then call

```
$ws->setCellValue()
```

to set your cell values.

or use the fluent interface:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $first_line)
    ->setCellValue('B'.$row, ucwords($dataRow['intlcode']))
    ->setCellValue('C'.$row, ucwords($dataRow['mobile_number']))
    ->setCellValue('D'.$row, ucwords($dataRow['r_datetime']))
    ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $dataRow['fname'])
    ->setCellValue('F'.$row, $dataRow['lname'])
    ->setCellValue('G'.$row, $dataRow['email'])
    ->setCellValue('H'.$row, $dataRow['picture'])
    ->setCellValue('I'.$row, $dataRow['lang'])
    ->setCellValue('J'.$row, $dataRow['interests'])
    ->setCellValue('K'.$row, $dataRow['title'])
    ->setCellValue('L'.$row, $dataRow['company'])
    ->setCellValue('M'.$row, $dataRow['address'])
    ->setCellValue('N'.$row, $dataRow['app_status']);
```

Even better if you can use the fromArray() method to set all the cells in the row in a single call.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataRow,NULL,'B'.$row);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! Will try your suggestions. Thanks for the logical explanation as for how I can save some repeated operations.

Comment: Mark you're awesome man.. blink of eye.. File got downloaded.

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately, I am ending up with an Fatal error for memory. The worksheet I am exporting now is having about 1700 rows and 15 columns. My memory limit is set to 128Mb on the server. The server admin advices it has to be lower. Your above suggestions I have implemented. What they recommend is 48Mb memory limit. Is there a solution that I could continue using PHPExcel lib within the memory range prescribed by server admin. I opted PHP Excel oz it gives the freedom to dump images on the excel file. Otherwise, I was using something like: http://pastebin.com/ZNCTUEBR

Comment: I am looking for a solution to rather than holding the workbook in the memory and writing it later.. I want to write incrementally. Could you please provide me a demonstration of such a method if exists in the library. I read the documentation and was unable not find it and I searched on the forum too

Comment: @Prashant - I'm not aware of any library that does an incremental write (and I know most of the tools for writing Excel), if you want a real Excel file... the pastebin method you've linked is also "in memory", and doesn't even offer the option of cacheing. One option that PHPExcel gives to reduce memory usage is cell cacheing, fully described in the documentation. Your alternative is to write something like a CSV file or an HTML file which can be done incrementally.

Comment: I looked into the cell caching concept and seems like it works for me. However, I am still waiting confirmation. Please suggest if there's any other way to reduce memory usage.

Comment: There's a lot of information in the PHPExcel discussion forums, such as using cell cacheing, setting styles (including number format masking) by range rather than for each individual cell... but your biggest saving would come from passing the database resource to your function and inserting each excel row from a fetched row rather than fetching every row to a big array and passing that array to your function

Comment: Thanks for the second lead.. I will try to follow this one as well.